# How does strtok_s tokenize a char*?

Tags: c

It seems to have modified the original string that I wanted to split specifying tokens.

how does it return back a substring if it can't copy from memory?

I'm also looking for an alternative that accepts a `const char*` Or doesn't modify the orignal string.

Or is it safe to just `const_cast` the string to remove the const property and let it be handled by `strtok_s(char*, const char*, char**)`.?

Comment: `const_cast` is from C++, but your question is marked C. If you want a C++ solution, you might want to consider using string streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok_s` et al **do** modify the strings passed in, so no, you can't pass in a `const_cast`d constant string.  What it does is if it finds a delimiter, it replaces that delimiter with a NUL terminator to separate the string into two pieces.  It then returns a pointer to the first part, which is now the desired null-terminated token.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the original string, you can always copy it first and then `strtok_s` it.